# Wrong output from eval function Python

Tags: python, scripting

Can you please explain why this expression evaluates to 0?

```
eval("(2==2|2==3)") # this is evaluated to 0 instead of 1
```

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't evaluate to 0 or 1. It evaluates to `False`.

Comment: Use `or` (Boolean or), not `|` (bitwise or)

Comment: (But also, don't use `eval()`. There are _very_ few places where that function is appropriate and it is very easy to introduce security problems if you use it improperly. It isn't doing anything useful here.)

Comment: `2|2` equals 2. Your expression is equivalent to `2==(2|2) and (2|2)==3`, which is false.

Comment: What do you not understand from the documentation on operator precedence?

Comment: @Chris and what you you suggest to use instead of eval?

Comment: Simply `(2==2|2==3)`. Why do you think you need `eval()`?

Comment: Can you please explain why you think it should evaluate to 1?

Comment: @Chris I cant put it in if condition, I need to evaluate this, that put it in string, evaluate that and so on

Comment: @StepanHarutyunyan, I don't understand what you mean. Please provide an example (likely in a separate question; the comments aren't the right place to ask a new one). But I'm quite sure that you shouldn't be using `eval()` here. You definitely do _not_ need `eval()` simply to use `if`. See [ask].

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong operator, and so you're also getting the wrong precedence.

In Python, `or` has lower precedence than `==`, while `|` has higher precedence.  Your expression is being evaluated as `2 == (2|2) == 3` which is `2 == 2 == 3` which is `False`.

You want `2 == 2 or 2 == 3` which is evaluated as `(2 == 2) or (2 == 3)` which is `True`.